# redirect two links from https to http

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Recently we added https in our site, But in two links we are using iframe which is targeting on http website( https is not available ). So we are thinking we will redirect these two urls from https to http. 
We added redirection but its not working. 
Please tell us what we are doing wrong. Here is our .htaccess file

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
Redirect 301  https://www.mydomain.co.in/marketrates/ http://www.kisansanchar.co.in/marketrates/
Redirect 301  https://mydomain.co.in/marketrates http://www.mydomain.co.in/marketrates
Redirect 301  https://www.mydomain.co.in/weather/checklocalweather.htm http://www.mydomain.co.in/weather/checklocalweather.htm
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using mod_rewrite instead, the `Redirect` directive is part of mod_alias and you can't check if the requested host or whether it's HTTP or HTTPS (unless you've placed them in a specific vhost instead of an htaccess file).

So something like this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^(marketrates/?|weather/checklocalweather\.htm)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
```